How should I get the above price on google flight with cheerio on GAS?
var URL = "<https://www.google.com/travel/flights/s/fhfbNzzwytaS3Xgs8>";

let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL);

let $ = Cheerio.load(response.getContentText(),{decodeEntities:false})

let data = $('div,span').text();
Logger.log(data);

Hi. I try to get the above price on Google Flight

but the result are the other words, doesn't output any price at all.

So how should I get correct price result that I want?

I don't think it's doable with GAS--looks like the price is loaded with JS, so you might be able to search the network tab for the response that contains the price and try hitting that endpoint directly. Or use a browser automation solution with Node.

Okey.Thank you.
